# Troubleshooting 'Unknown record property / related component "user" on "sfGuardUserProfile"' when loading fixture data

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard, symfony-plugins

I am some trouble loading fixture data, that I have added manually in my admin backend and then simply exported the data using 'symfony doctrine:data-dump'

schema.yml
http://pastebin.com/5LTzNtU1

fixtures.yml (snippet)
http://pastebin.com/CNWyhrgc

Now everything works fine when I run `symfony doctrine:build --all`, but when i try to load the data, I get:

`Unknown record property / related component "user" on "sfGuardUserProfile"`

This is really odd, as I have saved users and they've gone into both tables fine, just not when loading the fixtures that I exported fomr the database.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. create users.yml with

```
sfGuardUser:
  sfGuardUser_1:
    email_address: test@example.com
    username: test_user
    algorithm: sha1
    salt: 6fdcd99a2c73d6270f1ed8dbbf7ccd3e
    password: fed98ad16c318197d16a2d7375f81e1afbce0792
    is_active: true
    is_super_admin: true
    last_login: '2011-05-03 09:37:08'
    first_name: ''
    last_name: ''
    created_at: '2011-04-11 11:29:02'
    updated_at: '2011-05-03 09:37:08'
```

and profile.yml with

```
sfGuardUserProfile:
  sfGuardUserProfile_1:
    User: sfGuardUser_1
    email_new: test@example.com
    firstname: Test
    lastname: User
    validate_at: null
    validate: null
    created_at: '2011-04-19 15:46:16'
    updated_at: '2011-04-19 15:49:14'
```

Maybe it help you.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It seems like the `User` relation doesn't seemt o be working...

Comment: My example was generated form `doctrine:data-dump`, which is strange it wont let me load the data back in..

Comment: Ok, so it seems I had some schema.yml from a plugin overriding my config/doctrine/schema.yml file. I removed the data in the plugin schema.yml file, re-built models and all is working now!